# Can I throw custom exception inside a loop?

Tags: apex, exception, dml-operations

I've created a custom exception class by extending Exception {}
my question is, can I throw a custom exception inside a loop. does Apex consider throwing a custom exception as a DML operation

Below is the sample code

```
public class InfoException extends Exception {}
for (Id sObjectId : mySObjects.keySet()) {
if(Some condition check)
throw new InfoException('Bad Record.');
}
```

Comment: This appears to be an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You might want to post a question that actually explains what you're trying to do.

Comment: "does Apex consider throwing a custom exception as a DML operation" - no.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can throw custom exception inside a loop.

Apex doesn't consider it as DML operation, since you are not performing a DML operation.

There are separate exceptions for DML operation which Salesforce provides. Refer [Exception Class and Built-In Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can demonstrate for yourself by ruining this anonymous script:

```
class MyException extends Exception { }
try
{
    throw new MyException('msg');
}
catch (MyException e)
{
    system.assertEquals(0, Limits.getDmlStatements());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You throw custom exception from a for loop by writing a try catch block

```
for (loop consition)
{

   try
   {
      if (condition)
      {
          throw new CustomException();
      }
   } catch (CustomException e)
   {
      e.setMessage('Some Error Message')
      Apex.addMessages(e);
      break;
   }
}
```

By Using `break` statement you can terminate the loop and the message will shown on the page